# Get something up

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm reading the Godfather by `M. Puzo` and there is a dialog:

> "The great Johnny Fontane stuck without a date," she said
>
> "The great
>   Johnny Fontane is lucky if he can even **get it up** anymore," he said

What is this ***get it up***. I thought that getting up is that what we do right after waking up in the morning. But that doesn't seem to fit in this case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["To get it up"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20it%20up) is a slang phrase that refers to the ability to get an erection.

If the phrase were simply "to get up", without "it," then you're right that it would mean "to get out of bed after waking up."

Comment: To be clear, "get it up" means this and *only* this. It's not something you should use unless you are clear on when and where it's acceptable, and it's not really a structure that you can modify to fit other meanings.